# How do i loop each column of a class in List<class> using for each in c#

Tags: c#

How do i Set insertion of class dynamically?

how do i get each column of class  to set in the foreach loop?
How to set each column of IEmployee or Custom class in List<> to be paired with the string[] values in foreach loop?

I'm trying to insert the the custom class to database dynamically using foreach loop. without using for loop.

if there is a way to insert a custom class dynamically without using for loop
Below are the codes :

```
public class Employee : IEmployee
{
    private string _fname;
    public string Firstname
    {
        get { return _fname; }
        set { _fname = value; }
    }

    private string _lname;
    public string Lastname
    {
        get { return _lname; }
        set { _lname = value; }
    }

    private int _age;

    public int Age
    {
        get { return _age; }
        set { _age = value; }
    }

    private Gender _sex;
    public Gender Sex
    {
        get { return _sex; }
        set { _sex = value; }
    }

    private string _position;
    public string Position
    {
        get { return _position; }
        set { _position = value; }
    }

    private DateTime _bday;
    public DateTime BirthDay
    {
        get { return _bday; }
        set { _bday = value; }
    }  
}


string[] empcoltest = 
    {
        "userid",
        "fname",
        "mname",
        "lname",
        "gender",
        "position",
        "birthday"

    };




public void function(List<IEmployee> EmpList)
{
  string[] columns, values;
        columns = empcoltest;
        values = new string[columns.Length];
        for (int a = 0; a < columns.Length; a++)
        {
            columns[a] = columns[a].Trim();
            values[a] = "@col" + a.ToString();
        }
    string strEmp2 = @"INSERT INTO tblEmployees(" + string.Join(", ", columns) + ") VALUES(" + string.Join(", ", values) + ")";


  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strEmp2, sqlDB.SqlDB))
  {
    sqlDB.connect();


    foreach (string t in values)
    {
       foreach (IEmployee Emp in )
        {
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(t,Emp);
        }
    }

  }

}
```

what i want to do is something like this

```
 foreach (string t in values)
 {
   foreach (IEmployee Emp in )
   {
     //how do i set the Emp dynamically
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(t,Emp);

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to provide more details when posting your code, don't just  put code all at once.
You can use reflection to loop through your class, and set value or get value or get name of property and more.
Recommendation to this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y8-uq6Ur7Dc tutorial about reflection.

I've made simple example in console app, just to illustrate

**Here is Employee class**

```
 class Employee
{
    public int FirstProp{ get; set; }
    public string SecondProp { get; set; }
}
```

Reflection method

```
  public static void EmployeeReflection(List<Employee> EmpList)
    {
        PropertyInfo[] pInfo = typeof(Employee).GetProperties();
        //or
        //  PropertyInfo[] pinfo = EmpList.GetType().GetProperties();
        for (int i= 0; i < EmpList.Count; i++)
            {
                string name = pInfo[i].Name;
                object value = pInfo[i].GetValue(EmpList[i]);
                Console.WriteLine("property name: " + name);
                Console.WriteLine("property value: " + value);
                Console.WriteLine("..........");

            }

            /* or using foreach
         int count = 0;
        foreach (Employee emp in EmpList)
        {
            string name = pInfo[count].Name;
            object value = pInfo[count].GetValue(emp);
            Console.WriteLine("property name: " + name);
            Console.WriteLine("property value: " + value);
            Console.WriteLine("..........");
            count++;
        }
        */

    }
```

**And calling the method**

```
      static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<Employee> listOfEmploies = new List<Employee>
        {
            new Employee { FirstProp = 1, SecondProp = "SomeText01" },
            new Employee { FirstProp = 2, SecondProp = "SomeText02" }
        };
       EmployeeReflection(listOfEmploies);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

You will also need `using System.Reflection`.

*Let me share my class that creates Select, Insert, Update and Delete query that i created when i was making app for my graduate work.

The condition for calling is that your classes have same name as SQL tables and properties in class are indexed same as columns in SQL table. When calling this class, constructor takses SqlConnection obj*

**Here is my class**

```
 class SqlHelper<T> where T : new()
{
    private PropertyInfo[] pInfo = typeof(T).GetProperties();
    private string sqlTable = typeof(T).Name; //i've made this filed becouse i've named my classes same as tables in SQL
    public SqlConnection Con { get; set; }
    private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    private List<string> columns = new List<string>();
    public SqlHelper(SqlConnection con)
    {
        this.Con = con;
    }

    private void GetNames()
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " + sqlTable, Con);
        try
        {
            Con.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            for (int i = 0; i < dr.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                if (!columns.Contains(dr.GetName(i)))
                    columns.Add(dr.GetName(i));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return;
        }
        finally
        {
            Con.Close();
        }
    }
    public List<T> ReturnSelect()
    {
        List<T> listGen = new List<T>();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " + sqlTable, Con);
        try
        {
            Con.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                T obj = new T();
                for (int i = 0; i < dr.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[i]))
                        pInfo[i].SetValue(obj, dr.GetValue(i));

                }
                listGen.Add(obj);

            }

            return listGen;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {          
            return null;
        }
        finally { Con.Close(); }
    }

    public bool InsertInto(T obj)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = Con;
        sb.Clear();
        sb.Append("INSERT INTO " + sqlTable + " VALUES(");
        if (columns.Count == 0)
            GetNames();
        string s1 = ",";
        for (int i = 1; i < columns.Count; i++)
        {
            if (columns.Count - 1 == i)
                s1 = ")";
            sb.Append("@" + pInfo[i].Name + s1);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + pInfo[i].Name, pInfo[i].GetValue(obj));

        }

        cmd.CommandText = sb.ToString();

        try
        {
            Con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            Con.Close();
        }
    }
    public bool Update(T obj)
    {
        sb.Clear();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = Con;
        sb.Append("UPDATE " + sqlTable + " SET ");
        string s1 = ",";
        if (columns.Count == 0)
            GetNames();
        for (int i = 1; i < columns.Count; i++)
        {
            if (columns.Count - 1 == i)
                s1 = "";
            sb.Append(columns[i] + "=" + "@" + pInfo[i].Name + s1);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + pInfo[i].Name, pInfo[i].GetValue(obj));
        }
        sb.Append(" WHERE " + columns[0] + "=" + "@" + pInfo[0].Name + ";");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + pInfo[0].Name, pInfo[0].GetValue(obj));

        cmd.CommandText = sb.ToString();

        try
        {
            Con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            Con.Close();
        }

    }
    public bool Delete(T obj)
    {
        if (columns.Count == 0)
            GetNames();
        string id = $"@{pInfo[0].Name}";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM " + sqlTable + " WHERE " + columns[0] + "=" + id, Con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(id, pInfo[0].GetValue(obj));
        try
        {
            Con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            Con.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

*For example this is how it works:*

```
 SqlHelper<Employee> hlp = new SqlHelper<Employee>(new SqlConnection
            (new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
            {
                DataSource = @"(local)\SQLEXPRESS",
                InitialCatalog = "SomeDatabase",
                IntegratedSecurity = true
            }.ToString()));

        Employee e = new Employee { FirstProp = 3, SecondProp = "SomeText3" };
        List<Employee> list = hlp.ReturnSelect();
        bool Insertresult= hlp.InsertInto(e);
        bool Updateresult=hlp.Update(e);
        bool Deleteresult=hlp.Delete(e);
```

Hope this helps.